# Is this code correctly translated from objective-c to swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard

Hi i am trying to convert this code from Objective-c to Swift. Can anyone please confirm if this is correct or if anything needs changing.

```
- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

UIStoryboard *storyboard;

// detect the height of our screen
int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

if (height == 480) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main3.5" bundle:nil];
} else if (height == 568) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main4.0" bundle:nil];
}else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main7.0" bundle:nil];
}

return storyboard;
}
```

This is what i have so far.

```
func grabStoryboard() {

var storyboard = UIStoryboard()

var height = UIScreen .mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if(height == 480){
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "3.5", bundle: nil)
    } else if(height == 568){
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "4.0", bundle: nil)
    }else{
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "7.0", bundle: nil)
    }


}
```

I also need help translating

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];
self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard      instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and

```
    return storyboard;
```

Comment: what is your exact problem. explain clearly.

Comment: Sorry my problem is not clear. I just needed help translating my objective-c code to swift. I am new to programming and especially to swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good try. But little change should be there to correct your code in swift.

```
let storyboard:UIStoryboard = self.grabStoryboard()
    self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UIViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And method to get storyboard is like:

```
func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard()
    var height = UIScreen .mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if(height == 480) {

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "3.5", bundle: nil)

    } else if(height == 568) {

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "4.0", bundle: nil)

    } else {

        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "7.0", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard
}
```

Comment: Welcome... please vote this answer so it will be helpful to others. ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your problem but your swift method should be like this

```
func grabStoryboard()-> UIStoryboard {

    var storyboard:UIStoryboard?

    var height = UIScreen .mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if(height == 480){
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "3.5", bundle: nil)
    } else if(height == 568){
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "4.0", bundle: nil)
    }else{
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "7.0", bundle: nil)
    }

    return storyboard!;
}
```

Comment: My problem was that i could not translate my objective-c code to swift. Thank you for helping me out.